# Still getting ioBit notifications after uninstalling Driver Booster Free

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I got a new Acer laptop in Jan 2019. Due to a host of issues, I was advised to use Driver Booster to upgrade drivers.  I'm not sure if it helped, but recently, it threw up a notification that did not have a GUI control for banishing it.  I forgot what the notification was, but not something I was interested in.  It persistently blocked out a good portion  of the lower right quadrant of my screen.  I didn't have a lot of personal free time remaining that day and I was really trying to accomplish a particular to-do.  This ad essentially eliminated any hope of doing so, as I had to spend the rest of the time figuring out that I couldn't get rid of the ad, then uninstalling Driver Booster.

Since then, I've still gotten an ioBit notification that my browser has left traces that could compromise my security.

How is this even possible when I've erased Driver Booster?

How can I completely erase all traces of ioBit?

Comment: Can you provide the notifications you have received? Difficult to help you solve a problem without those details

Comment: The first one was about a week ago.  I don't remember.  The second one was about traces of information left behind by my browser.  I described it as best as I remember it in my post.  But the problem is the same.  ioBit should be all gone, but it isn't.

Comment: *I was advised to use Driver Booster to upgrade drivers* -> Very bad advice. Keep this is mind next time the same source gives you "advice".

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I got this advice 1.5 years ago on the Acer forum site.  I assumed that they knew what they were talking about, but maybe that's a bad idea. I also googled Driver Booster right now, and there are no indications of its indavisability.  It's not until I googled my specific problem (inability to clean it out, and ads) did I see the problem. It makes me wonder what best practice is for vetting suggested 3rd party solutions.

Comment: @Ramhound: Unfortunately, the information is banished, else I would have added it to the posted question after your last comment.  I think the real problem, however, is getting rid of ioBit.  Suggestions on the ioBit forum include "Look in Program Files x86 and Appdata......and remove any Iobit folders".  I'll try that first, then resort to `Revo Uninstaller Portable` if I still have problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

1. Download [Revo Uninstaller Portable](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) - it's a paid product but there's 30 day trial period w. unlimited functionality
2. Re-download Driver Booster
3. Run RU
4. Install DB with RU:s Install -button - it will trace the entire installation
5. Once the installation has finished, you need to run DB once, but you can close it immediately after - just check that it doesn't stay running on the taskbar
6. Save the installation log on RU
7. Check RU:s "Traced" - you should find DB there
8. Uninstall DB with RU - at the end it will comb through the registry and your drive for any leftovers so you can delete them

You need to just unpack RU Portable and run it from the folder. Since it doesn't install you won't get any surprises. And once you're done, you can just trash the folder.

Comment: Thanks, Peregrino69.  I'm going to mull this for a bit.  Downloading and installing more 3rd party things was something I was trying to avoid.  I appreciate the option, though.

Comment: Everything and I do mean everything that Revo Uninstaller can be done by hand. Without specifics I cannot provide more specific instructions

Comment: Yes I know - that's why I suggested the portable version which does not require installation at all. @Ramhound is correct, everything RU does *can* be done manually. It's just more difficult, and prone to errors. Also about shovelware :-D I just installed Advanced System Care for a comparison test. After uninstallation I got an ioBit notification about browser protection.

Comment: iOBit always needs a pick, shovel, axe, saw, magnifying glass & fine tweezers to pick out of a system. I learned to avoid that particular plague many years ago. Revo won't hurt & can easily be removed if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Luckily my reflexes are good enough to get my hand in the way... I managed to avoid the laptop and spewed coffee only all over my shirt and desk... :-D

Comment: Sorry about that - have fresh ones on me ;)) ☕️

Comment: A suggestion on the ioBit forum was to "Look in Program Files x86 and Appdata......and remove any Iobit folders".  I'll try that first, then resort to `Revo Uninstaller Portable` if I still have problems.  Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. @Tetsujin's quip about the necessary tools is not an overstatement :-) Cleaning it out from the registry manually is practically impossible.

Comment: So far so good. My concern about tracing the DB's installation process is that they've progressed several versions over the intervening years.

Comment: ... and now you're starting to understand @Tetsujin's point... You basically have just the two options: either hunt everything down manually, or since MS doesn't provide a tool for the purpose use some 3rd party application to do the job for you.

Comment: I do appreciate what he revealed about the difficulty of removing the software.  I'm don't think I was entirely clear in my last comment. Since DB's version has progressed, I'm not sure how well its installation process can be traced/tracked.  I'm not familiar enough with this.  So unless I can find the original installer, and it doesn't phone home for the most recent version, I'm afraid that even this approach would be problematic.  If I get no more ads, I won't worry about it.  :(

Comment: Worth a try nonetheless. Generally new versions of applications tend to install on the already familiar ground, i.e. where the older version was. There are also good cleaning utilities for hunting down and removing leftover remnants of old, uninstalled applications. You were very clear - we're all old Win users so we know the pains :-D